# Is there a way to disable hover bar / mode bar in plotly.py?

Tags: python, plotly

so using the bare minimum code to produce a chart in plotly.py:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter
plot([Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[3, 2, 1, 2, 3])])
```

produces a nice chart with a modebar on top of it. I would like to embed my chart in a website where the bar seems really intrusive. In plotly.js there's a really simple way to disable to modebar as shown [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/configuration-options/#hide-the-modebar-with-plotlyjs). The solution in plotly.js is merely giving additional parameter: `Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {displayModeBar: false});`

I know there's a way to save static image from plotly where the modebar is obviously disabled, but that would lose the interactive hover-actions on the plot itself, which are useful, whereas the bar that comes with it is not really that useful in my case. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to do remove the modebar in a similiar fashion to how plotly.js works?

One solution, I suppose would be to always go through the produced HTML-file and add every part of the hover bar to r.modeBarButtonsToRemove, which could turn troublesome in the long run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been able to do it using the config key word argument, like this:

```
graph = py.plot(
                figure,
                output_type='div',
                auto_open=False,
                show_link=False,
                config=dict(
                    displayModeBar=False
                )
            )
```

Comment: Yeah, apparently they added the `displayModeBar` parameter (and few others) in [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/pull/410) fix. Thanks!

Comment: The plot.ly version I was using at the time I was asking would've produced this error message with that code: `TypeError: plot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'`. So if anyone sees anything like that, updating plot.ly should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late here. But just a side note, this won't disable the functions of the top bar so when you hover it will still zoom and pan (which is extremely annoying on plots that are viewed from a mobile device). But making it a static plot isn't a good solution because I still want users on a computer to be able to hover over the points on the plot.

I solved this by changing two of the figure layout settings.
`xaxis_fixedrange` and `yaxis_fixedrange` need to be set to `True` if you want to disable zooming.